Can you use bombs with Spiritual Armament?
Wearing an Acid Flask and after casting Spiritual Armament, can I use Spiritual Armament to deal acid damage?
I'm also not sure if the intent is to use weapons that deal a physical damage type, or if the part "After the Attack, the weapon returns to your side" makes sense with something like an Acid Flask.

So basically it boils to "are bombs (Player Core pg. 453) weapons?" or is there something more to cause problems?

@Mołot Well... yes, but I'm also not sure if the intent is to use weapons that deal a physical damage type, or if the part "After the Attack, the weapon returns to your side" makes sense with something like an Acid Flask. Should I update the question?

Yes

You create a ghostly, magical echo of one weapon you’re wielding or wearing and fling it.

Alchemical bombs are weapons and would qualify to be echoed by spiritual armament. There are baked-in limitations to consumables which prevent things like weapon runes from being applied, but those don't seem to preclude this combination:

As consumables, bombs can't have runes etched onto them, have talismans attached to them, or benefit from runes granted in other ways (such as from spells or from items that replicate runes from other items). Spells and magic items that give you a bonus to all your attacks (or to all thrown weapons, for example) can still apply to them.

The spell deals the same 2d8 damage for any weapon, of the same damage type as the weapon or as spirit damage as determined by the GM. Most alchemical bombs only really deal one damage type and should be fairly straightforward to adjudicate—your example of using an acid flask would deal 2d8 acid or spirit damage. Note that persistent damage isn't a damage type but rather a condition and damage.

This appears as “X persistent [type] damage,” where “X” is the amount of damage dealt and “[type]” is the damage type. Like normal damage, it can be doubled or halved based on the results of an attack roll or saving throw.

Splash damage is a bit trickier to show as definitely not applying, but with other weapon traits also generally being ignored in favor of just the 2d8 damage that likely means any splash damage wouldn't apply for the attack from spiritual armament.

After the attack, the weapon returns to your side.

Based on the first line of the spell, the actual weapon never leaves the caster. Instead this line seems to refer to the magical echo of the weapon that was flung at the target, which a bit more reasonable to have return after the spell's attack concludes and allows for it to be flung again whenever the spell is Sustained.

Consider including this part of the rules directly in your answer: "Bombs are martial thrown weapons with a range increment of 20 feet."
